# SSH forcecommand, but don't limit root

Tags: ssh, bash, linux

I was using ssh's "forcecommand" option to pass a shell script that would help lock out users from ssh.  I was wondering if their was a way to do this without forcing root to have to execute the shell script as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

sshd allows us to override default settings for selected user (User, Group, Host or Address).

We can accompilsh this using `Match` block. In `Match` block we must set condition and settings that we want to change.

I don't know if it is possible to unset option in `sshd_config` (for example by using option without args), but if it isn't possible you could create group of users that you want to restrict and apply `ForceCommand` only to that group.

Config with unset option:

```
Match User root
       ForceCommand #some way to unset option?
```

Config with restricted group:

```
Match Group restrictedsshd
       ForceCommand /some/script.sh
```

More info about `Match` option you could find in `man sshd_config`.

Answer (score 0):

From `man sshd (LOGIN PROCESS)`:
`3. Checks /etc/nologin; if it exists, prints contents and quits (unless root).`